# Union of intersection and intersection of union for arbitrary events

Tags: probability

I was working with this Billingsley's problem.

I would like to prove that $$ U_k=I_{n−k+1} $$

where $$U_k=∪(A_{i_1}∩...∩A_{i_k})$$ and $$I_k=∩(A_{i_1}∪...∪A_{i_k})$$

and the union and intersection extend over all the k-tuples satisfying 
$$1≤i_1<i_2....<i_k≤n$$

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Review distributive laws for unions and intersections. Abbreviated version:

$$A(B \cup C) = AB \cup AC = A \cup BC,$$

where I have written 'multiplication' for
intersection.

Comment: Brings back memories. Took courses from Billingsley.

Comment: Good tip. Thank you.

Comment: I calculated the complement of $$I_{n−k+1}$$. So I could see that $$I_{n−k+1} ⊆ U_k $$.